# How to easily inspect styled-components using dev tools?

Tags: styled-components

I am using styled-components in a React project. When the components are rendered in the browser they are assigned a randomly generated classname, for example:

`<div class="sc-KSdffgy oPwefl">`

This class name does not help me identify from which component the `<div>` came from, so is there a way to do this easily?

P.s. currently I am adding attrs to my styled components so that I can recognise them in dev tools, for example:

```
const Foo = styled.div.attrs({
   'data-id': 'foo'
})`
    ...
`;
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That's exactly why we created our [Babel plugin](https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components), when using it you'll get class names that include the name you gave your component:

```
<div class="Sidebar__Button-KSdffgy oPwefl">
```

On top of that we set the `displayName` of the generated component too, which means in your React DevTools you'll see the actual component name rather than just <div> or <Styled(Component)>.

To use the Babel plugin install it with `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components` and then add it to your Babel configuration: (e.g. in your `.babelrc`)

```
plugins: ["styled-components"]
```

That's it! Happy debugging

---

*Note that if you're using `create-react-app` you cannot change the Babel configuration. I use and would recommend [`react-app-rewired`](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to be able to change configurations without having to eject. We've also built [`react-app-rewire-styled-components`](https://github.com/withspectrum/react-app-rewire-styled-components) which automatically integrates the styled-components Babel plugin for you!*

Comment: This is great, but I was also wondering - is there a way to also see the props passed to the Styled Component? For example, let's say I have a `<Text primary>...</Text>`, I'd like to see the `primary` in devtools but at the moment it's a randomly generated classname as well.

Comment: For anyone Googling, the Webpack config here was what I needed to get nicer looking classes for debugging purposes: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#minification

Comment: awesome answer, that helped me a lot thanks!

Answer (score 27):

For anyone using create-react-app, just substitute

```
import styled from "styled-components";
```

to

```
import styled from "styled-components/macro";
```

this will make your styled-component classes have the name of their component in them. And you'll be able to know which classes refer to which components just by looking at their class name ;)

Comment: @tif it literally solves the problem so yeah. great contribution, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for updating the question @n-joppi

Comment: Doesn't work for me...

Comment: This does not work anymore.

Comment: Yes but you have to change the import **everywhere**. What do you do in a large project?

Answer (score 10):

For anyone using `create-react-app`, another option is to use the [styled components babel macro](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-macro)

1. `npm install --save babel-plugin-macros`
2. Inside your component use `import styled from 'styled-components/macro';` instead of `import styled from 'styled-components';`

You should now see the component name in your dev tools:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work to me

Answer (score 7):

I was looking at doing the same and stumbled on the following as an alternative to attrs:

```
const Section = styled.div`
  background-color: #06183d;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  ${breakpoint("md")`
    border-radius: 5px;
  `}
`

Section.defaultProps = {
  "data-id": "Section"
}
```

Use React.Component's `defaultProps`. It keeps the call to `styled.div` cleaner and should be easier to remove if needed.

Results in:
[image]

Comment: Works great! I created a simple snippet to make it more convenient.
 `"prefix": "cy", "body": [ "$CLIPBOARD.defaultProps = { \"data-styled-id\": \"$CLIPBOARD\" };" ]`. Basically it gets the id from the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

In Next 13 adding this to `next.config.js` worked:

```
compiler: {
    styledComponents: true
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ts-loader` or `awesome-typescript-loader` there is [typescript-plugin-styled-components](https://github.com/Igorbek/typescript-plugin-styled-components).