# How to show correct displayName in react-scripts-ts projects when using Styled Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am using [react-scripts-ts](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) and styled-components for my React-typescript web app. Components created using styled-components do not seem to show the correct displayName when debugging; instead they show a fallback like `styled.div` or `styled.span`.

E.g.

```
const Bar = styled.div`
  background: #ddd;
`;
...
return <Bar />;
```

This will show *styled.div* as display name instead of *Bar* in the React dev tools.

PS: Styled-components suggests a babel plugin that works for CRA apps. But I see no docs on if there is a similar solution for react-typescript-ts projects.

Comment: you need to use the `babel-plugin-styled-components` package, which gives a lot of nice tooling for your styled components. [Docs for reference](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to easily inspect styled-components using dev tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504955/how-to-easily-inspect-styled-components-using-dev-tools)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of importing styled-components like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

Import it like this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';
```

If that isn't working for you it is likely that you need to update styled-components or react. Further information can be found in the [styled-components documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling).

Comment: Works even with typescript build.

Comment: I spend so many hours just to find this answer. Tks bro!