# How can I disable classname obfuscation for development only

Tags: reactjs

In a React app, how can I disable classname obfuscation for development only?

I want to see the following only in production build,
but in the development when I run "npm start" I want to see the classnames unobfuscated.

`<div class="sc-kYrkKh bteCVQ">`

Reason: when i want to look at an html element in the browser, I want to be able to easily see the component name.

I have seen this (ie. classname confuscation on production only) in multiple projects, but I did not configure it myself, and I don't know/remember how it's done.

In my current specific case (=project) we are using styled components, but perhaps it doesn't matter.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Solution? No. I did a lot of search, but haven't found a solution to this, yet. (There may be possibilities requiring installing extra packages, or changing configurations "inside" the node_modules folder, but I don't want to go there.)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the answer is [Babel plugin](https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components).

From its [documentation](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-plugin):

> In your page source you'll see: `<button class="Button-asdf123 asdf123" />` instead of just `<button class="asdf123" />`.

> It also allows you to see the component's displayName in React DevTools. For example, consider writing a styled component that renders a button element, called MyButton. It will normally show up in DevTools as styled.button, but with the displayName option enabled, it has the name you gave it: MyButton.

This makes it easier to find your components and to figure out where they live in your app.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45505519/18272040

Comment: Thanks. But if I understand it correctly, (1) this "babel-plugin-styled-components" tool requires modifying babel config, and (2) create-react-app does not support modifying babel config by default. So one needs to install more plugins. In other words, we have to install babel-plugin-styled-components to make styled-components to work like we want, and then we have to install more plugins to0 make babel-plugin-styled-components to work. For something which styled-components should have been supporting in the first place :o/