# re export styled from styled components macro not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I want to export `styled-components/macro` from my own `.ts` file but it is not working.

**custom-styled.ts**

```
import styled  from 'styled-components/macro'
import * as styledComponents from 'styled-components' 


import { ThemeInterface } from './theme'

const {
  css,
  createGlobalStyle,
  keyframes,
  withTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} = styledComponents as styledComponents.ThemedStyledComponentsModule<ThemeInterface>


export { css, createGlobalStyle, keyframes, ThemeProvider, withTheme }
export default styled
```

**App.tsx:** when I import it directly from import styled from 'styled-components/macro' it gives intended debugging features. But when I try from my **own file**, there is a problem. Thank you beforehand.

I tried with `export { css, createGlobalStyle, keyframes, ThemeProvider, withTheme, styled }`. But without success.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from './custom-styled'

const StyledContainer = styled.div`
background: black;
`
const StyledSpan = styled.span`
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
`

function App() {
    return (
        <StyledContainer>
            <StyledSpan>
                Test
            </StyledSpan>
        </StyledContainer>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Expected result should be:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post will help you [How to easily inspect styled-components using dev tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45505519/15545116)

Comment: @ЖнецЪ Solution using react-app-rewrite I think is not optimal for v4.x+ as it said in documentation. I think I need to write a GitHub issue in the styled-components repo about this problem.
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

If you are using *typescript* you must import `@types/styled-components`:

```
npm i @types/styled-components
```

Also needs `babel-plugin-styled-components`:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components
```

And create a `.babelrc` config file in the root derictory.

##### .babelrc

```js
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components",
      {
        "ssr": true,
        "minify": true,
        "transpileTemplateLiterals": false,
        "pure": false,
        "displayName": false, // generate another classname
        "fileName": false, // generate another classname
        "preprocess": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

##### App.tsx

```js
import styled, {
  Thing,
  GlobalStyle,
  StyledContainer,
  StyledSpan
} from "./custom-styled";
import Reusable from "./Reusable";

const StyledContainer2 = styled(StyledContainer)``;
const StyledSpan2 = styled(StyledSpan)``;
const StyledSpan3 = styled(StyledSpan)`
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <StyledContainer2>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Thing>Thing from suctom-styled</Thing>
      <StyledSpan2>StyledSpan</StyledSpan2>
      <StyledSpan3>Extend StyledSpan</StyledSpan3>
      <Reusable />
    </StyledContainer2>
  );
}

export default App;
```

##### custom-styled.ts

```js
import styled, {
  css,
  createGlobalStyle,
  keyframes,
  ThemeProvider
} from "styled-components/macro";

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: lightcoral;
  }
`;
export const Thing = styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

const move = keyframes`
  50%{ transform: translateX(100px)}
`;

export const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  background: black;
`;
export const StyledSpan = styled.span`
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation: ${move} 2s linear infinite;
`;

export { css, createGlobalStyle, keyframes, ThemeProvider };
export default styled;
```

##### Reusable.tsx

```js
import { Thing, StyledContainer, StyledSpan } from "./custom-styled";

function Reusable() {
  return (
    <StyledContainer>
      <Thing>Reusable Thing</Thing>
      <StyledSpan>Reusable StyledSpan</StyledSpan>
    </StyledContainer>
  );
}

export default Reusable;
```

##### DOM inspector local

[image]

##### React DevTool local

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer. In the first example, we cannot see more detailed names for example `styled-StyledSpan`. Because I wanted better debugging names and import styled-components from one place.

Comment: You cann't create component with dash. Or do you mean remove unnecessary generated classes and add custom classes names?
Is `custom-styled.ts` the place where you will store `styled-components`?

Comment: Problem that I couldn’t solve is re export styled-components/macro from custom-styled.ts. Reason for that is for better debugging names for components. Without styled-components/macro it gives standard name. For example styled-span. If I import styled-components/macro directly into my components instead of from custom-styled.ts, it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the sandbox and if i'm right understood you wanted class names like an in image above.

Comment: I tried in sandbox `"displayName": true` which should change in React dev tools from `styled.span` to `styled.StyledSpan`, but I didn't work. I need this because in my project I have maybe 5-10 divs and all of the same `styled.div` in React dev tools, and better debugging is necessary to distinguish these divs.

Comment: Hello, I have added a screenshot of the expected result. If I import `styled-components/macro` directly it works as expected but from custom-styled.ts it doesn't work.

Comment: I moved **StyledSpan** to *custom-styled* and removed all styles from *App.tsx* and *Reusable.tsx* in the sandbox . Also copied code from sandbox to local mashine for testing with **react devtool** and got the same result, what you will do expect. You can see in the screenshots above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238246/discussion-between-jasurbek-nabijonov-and-).

Comment: Updated the answer and sandbox. That last solution to came in my mind, is very close what you need.  This is all my knowledge about `styled-components`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think my team cannot adapt this solution because in that case, we need to create many boilerplates in custom-styled.ts. We have icons, images, different types of heading, and other tags. I will try to address this issue in styled-components github repo.